# How to create horizontal and vertical scroll in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am learning python and for designing app homescreen. I am stuck at creating horizontal and vertical ScrollView. Which layout i should use and how to implement both scroll?

Example: Horizontal & Vertical Scroll

[image]

Comment: I'd just nest two scroll layouts, does that not work? Please post the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

**Hay Ketan**, You can use nested ScrollView to add both of them to your application

**Full Code:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''

<Card>
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(150)
    elevation: dp(6)
    md_bg_color: .4, .77, .68, 1
    soft_shadow_cl: [0, 0, 0, .05]
    radius: dp(10)


MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: 1, 1
    
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        size_hint: 1, 1
        
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            col_force_default: False
            spacing: dp(6)
            size_hint: 1, None
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(6)
            
            
            Card:
            Card:
            
            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_y: False
                size_hint: 1, None
                adaptive_width: True
                height: dp(150)
                MDGridLayout:
                    rows: 1
                    row_force_default: False
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: dp(150)
                    spacing: dp(6)
                    adaptive_width: True
                    
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    Card:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        height: dp(150)
                        width: dp(150)
                        md_bg_color: .28, .68, .86, 1
                    
            Card:
            Card:
            Card:
        
'''

class Card(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    pass



class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

            

Example().run()
```

Here m using `do_scroll_x` & `do_scroll_x` Property of the ScrollView to restrict the wrong scrolls